# Crystal Report Error on Server - Unable to cast COM object of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

> Project: ASP.NET with C# 
>  
>   Visual Studio: 2017 
>  
>   Crystal Report: SAP CR for VS 13.0.21 
>  
>   Crystal Report Data Source: List<>

Working fine on Visual Studio. But not on the server. 
I have changed the properties of .rpt file to,

```
.# Build Action: Content.
.# Copy To Output Directory: Copy Always.
```

Error Details:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease) at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Refresh() at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.Refresh(RequestContext reqContext) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Refresh(RequestContext reqContext) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Refresh() at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(IEnumerable enumerable) at DSMS.web_UI.ViewCart.btnNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Programming\Xtra\Coding\Project\DSMS\DSMS\web_UI\ViewCart.aspx.cs:line 259

Comment: Make sure crystal report runtime 32/64 bit are installed on the target server.